# Angular JS. Need to display details on click event

Tags: angularjs

I have setup a plunker to demonstrate my question:
 http://plnkr.co/edit/xVtli2DKzNDCU1W99gOE?p=preview

The plunker lists the people with their brief details. What I need is, when the above boxes gets clicked, the complete person's details should be displayed in the "person-list" div.

How can we achieve using Angular JS?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/c7o3bvt7rdfVS9WlDZ0J?p=preview)?  The ng-click will set the scope with the selected person.

Comment: I seriously don't know what was I thinking. Pretty easy solution. Thanks a lot Sean. You have a good day.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but let the person be edited?